# Subdomains not working in nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to setup a nginx web server with one domain and one subdomain (`example.com` and `download.example.com`).

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/download;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name download.example.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    #listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    #ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    #ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    #include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

    #if ($scheme != "https") {
    #   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    #} # managed by Certbot

}
```

I can access `example.com`, but I can't access `subdomain.example.com`.

Logs:

    `Sep 16 19:53:32 vps456536 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
    Sep 16 19:53:32 vps456536 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
    Sep 16 19:53:32 vps456536 systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.`

DNS:

    `$TTL 3600
    @   IN SOA dns200.anycast.me. tech.ovh.net. (2017091608 86400 3600 3600000 300)
                              IN NS     dns200.anycast.me.
                              IN NS     ns200.anycast.me.
                              IN MX 1   mx1.mail.ovh.net.
                              IN MX 100 mx3.mail.ovh.net.
                              IN MX 5   mx2.mail.ovh.net.
                              IN A      SOME_IP
                              IN AAAA   SOME_IP
                              IN TXT    "1|example.com"
                          600 IN TXT    "v=spf1 include:mx.ovh.com ~all"
    _autodiscover._tcp        IN SRV    0 0 443 mailconfig.ovh.net.
    _imaps._tcp               IN SRV    0 0 993 ssl0.ovh.net.
    _submission._tcp          IN SRV    0 0 465 ssl0.ovh.net.
    autoconfig                IN CNAME  mailconfig.ovh.net.
    autodiscover              IN CNAME  mailconfig.ovh.net.
    ftp                       IN CNAME  example.com.
    imap                      IN CNAME  ssl0.ovh.net.
    mail                      IN CNAME  ssl0.ovh.net.
    pop3                      IN CNAME  ssl0.ovh.net.
    smtp                      IN CNAME  ssl0.ovh.net.
    www                       IN MX 1   mx1.mail.ovh.net.
    www                       IN MX 100 mx3.mail.ovh.net.
    www                       IN MX 5   mx2.mail.ovh.net.
    www                       IN A      SOME_IP
    www                       IN AAAA   SOME_IP
    www                       IN TXT    "l|pl"
    www                       IN TXT    "3|welcome"`

Comment: More details. Log entries, error messages, DNS configuration.

Comment: @Sven added logs and dns configuration.

Comment: For starters, I don't see any DNS entry for `download.example.com`. Please also add the access log and tell us what "can't access ...." means for you.

Comment: @Sven `INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND`. I don't have an access log.

Comment: What does that even mean? Context. Please read [How to ask better questions on Serverfault](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault)

Comment: @Sven on Chrome I get an error:
`This site can’t be reached
download.jqmey.net.pl’s server DNS address could not be found.
Search Google for download.example.com
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Answer (score 4):

Add an A record or CNAME for `download.example.com` to your DNS zone. Just defining a vhost in nginx is not sufficient for it to be found by clients, naturally.